# how to if combobox selection then directly checkbox unchecked in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, checkbox, combobox, vb.net-2010

How if ComboBox selection then directly CheckBox unchecked?

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_SelectionChangeCommitted(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles ComboBox1.SelectionChangeCommitted
    Me.TextBox1.Text = ""
    Me.PopulateDataGridView()
End Sub
Private Sub CheckBox1_CheckedChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles CheckBox1.CheckedChanged
    clearfiltercombobox()
    PopulateDataGridView()
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put `Me.CheckBox1.Checked = False` in your ComboBox handler

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_SelectionChangeCommitted(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles ComboBox1.SelectionChangeCommitted
    Me.TextBox1.Text = ""
    Me.CheckBox1.Checked = False
    Me.PopulateDataGridView()
End Sub
```